# Capturing a variable from a clicked link or url using php

Tags: url, php, mysql, custom-variables

I've build a php page called pageById.php that pulls in and displays data from a MySQL database, but the query is 'static'.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 879";
```

I want to change this so it uses a variable in-place of 879.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $var";
```

I'd like to be able to pull the $var from a link on the previous page or from the URL, but I'm not sure how.

Can someone please help or point me in the direction of a decent tutorial for beginners?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about programming websites are a better fit for StackOverflow.   Without the request for a tutorial this could be moved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about `GET` and `POST` variables.

This is really basic PHP stuff :P

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

This question is likely to be migrated to Stack Overflow where I am almost certain it will be a duplicate question